# Laravel - Disable the "select count" on load when using paginate method

Tags: laravel, count, pagination

I import an old database (hyperfile) to mysql to create a newapp with Laravel.

I'm using Laravel built in paginate method, but the first query "select count(*)" takes about 10 seconds to answer because there's about 70000 lines in this table.

I don't really need to know how many pages are present...just two buttons "previous/next" should be enough.
Is there a method to avoid this query ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Polaris. Please take a look at [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). A first result in Google for "laravel pagination prev next" leads me to [its documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/pagination), where you can use `simplePaginate` for avoiding that query and doing what you are asking.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/pagination

> **"Simple Pagination"**
>
> If you only need to display simple "Next" and "Previous" links in your pagination view, you have the option of using the `simplePaginate` method to perform a more efficient query. This is very useful for large datasets if you do not need to display a link for each page number when rendering your view:
>
> ```
> $users = DB::table('users')->simplePaginate(15);
> ```