# How to optimize query statement in Laravel 7?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-schema-builder

I show code in the screenshot, because I want to show you guys my line 43

[image]

The actual code is here :

```
public function index()
{
    $inputs    = Request::all();
    $interval  = '';

    if(array_key_exists('interval', $inputs)){
        $interval  = $inputs['interval'];
    }

    switch ($interval) {
        case 'day':
        $visitors = Visitor::where('created_at', '>', now()->today())->paginate(20);;
        break;
        case 'week':
        $visitors = Visitor::where('created_at', '>', now()->subMonth())->paginate(20);;
        break;
        case 'month':
        $visitors = Visitor::where('created_at', '>', now()->subMonth())->paginate(20);;
        break;
        case 'year':
        $visitors = Visitor::where('created_at', '>', now()->subYear())->paginate(20);
        break;
        default:
        $visitors = Visitor::orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')->paginate(20);
        break;
    }

    return View::make('layouts.be.visitors.index', get_defined_vars());
}
```

I visit

```
http://app.test/visitor?interval=year
```

## As you can see

Laravel Debugbar detected that I did 2 queries on line `43`

[image]

Why 2 ? Is this expected ?

Can I improve this into 1 ?

**Please advise**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel - Disable the "select count" on load when using paginate method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37729226/laravel-disable-the-select-count-on-load-when-using-paginate-method)

Comment: I think I answer below answered my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

second query is run by `paginate()` method.

If you look at this pagination response from laravel official documentation you will see one field called `total`. That's why that query runs to get total number of records:

```
{
   "total": 50,
   "per_page": 15,
   "current_page": 1,
   "last_page": 4,
   "first_page_url": "http://laravel.app?page=1",
   "last_page_url": "http://laravel.app?page=4",
   "next_page_url": "http://laravel.app?page=2",
   "prev_page_url": null,
   "path": "http://laravel.app",
   "from": 1,
   "to": 15,
   "data":[
        {
            // Result Object
        },
        {
            // Result Object
        }
   ]
}
```

That `select count(*) as aggregate from visitors WHERE created_at > '2019-03-13 12:22:22` query runs automatically.

If you want to set it manually you have to use `LengthAwarePaginator`.

> But I don't recomend to do that because of only one more query

See here about `LengthAwarePaginator`: https://github.com/laravel/ideas/issues/826

#### EDIT:

Here is how you can optimize your code:

```
use DB;
use Carbon\Carbon;
...
public function index()
{
    $inputs    = Request::all();
    $interval  = '';

    if(array_key_exists('interval', $inputs)){
        $interval  = $inputs['interval'];
    }

    $visitors = Visitor::when(in_array($interval, ['day', 'month', 'week', 'year']), function($q) use ($interval){
        return $q->where('created_at', '>', Carbon::parse("now -1 $interval"));
    }, function($q) {
        return $q->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc');
    })->paginate(20);

    return View::make('layouts.be.visitors.index', get_defined_vars());
}
```

See more about `when` method here: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#conditional-clauses

Hope this helps

Comment: Oh ok, I will just ignore that for now, then.

Comment: How do I access `"total"`, on my view ? I want to print it.

Comment: You can use `$visitors->total()`

Comment: I edited answer and look at it and use it if you prefer. If you find my answer helpful pleace mark it as accepted

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion on refactoring my codes. I’ll definitely take it into consideration 

Comment: I would like to stick Laravel codes as possible, I noticed you use SQL codes as part of ur suggestion. Possible to suggest with pure laravel syntax?

Comment: I edited code using carbon. You can also use `strtotime` method but since `now()` returns `Carbon` instance I did it with carbon. Don't forget to import it

Comment: Thank-you for that, I tried your codes, I notice 1 more tiny issue. When I'm at `http://app.test/visitor?interval=week` and click on (2) on pagination, I kept redirecting to `http://app.test/visitor?page=2` . Keep in mind that I am in a weekly view.

Comment: Is there a way to keep `?interval=week&page=2` ?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no official way. you have to do it yourself. Look at this question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9666909/keeping-url-parameters-during-pagination

Comment: It's okay, I found the solution to it. : https://stackoverflow.com/a/61193962/4480164

Answer (score 1):

It's because of the pagination object.
You want to run the LIMIT, but still know how many rows would have been returned without the LIMIT.
There is a way using mysql function [FOUND_ROWS()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows) but Laravel use the two queries way to count.

Comment: Maybe because `The SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS query modifier and accompanying FOUND_ROWS() function are deprecated as of MySQL 8.0.17 and will be removed in a future MySQL version`