# Pagination + URL Params in Laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, url-parameters, laravel-7

If I go to http://app.test/visitor?interval=week, I will see this

[image]

## Issue

As soon as I clicked on the second one, I got redirected to : http://app.test/visitor?page=2

[image]

It removed my `interval=week`, which ruined my query view for my weekly views.

---

## Code

This is how I construct my page

```
public function index()
{
    $inputs    = Request::all();
    $interval  = '';

    if(array_key_exists('interval', $inputs)){
        $interval  = $inputs['interval'];
    }

    switch ($interval) {
        case 'day':
        $visitors = Visitor::where('created_at', '>', now()->today())->paginate(10);;
        break;
        case 'week':
        $visitors = Visitor::where('created_at', '>', now()->subMonth())->paginate(10);;
        break;
        case 'month':
        $visitors = Visitor::where('created_at', '>', now()->subMonth())->paginate(10);;
        break;
        case 'year':
        $visitors = Visitor::where('created_at', '>', now()->subYear())->paginate(10);
        break;
        default:
        $visitors = Visitor::orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')->paginate(10);
        break;
    }


    return View::make('layouts.be.visitors.index', get_defined_vars());
}
```

## View

```
{!! $visitors->render() !!}
```

## Goal

is to stay in the same view, with something like this

`http://app.test/visitor?interval=week&page=2`

Do I have to overwrite the default pagination function?

How do I solve this issues ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the issue lies in the front end, when you press the #2 page in the pagination, you have to inject the interval query string to the end of each pagination button. What are you using as your front end? I'm pretty sure you will have to use some js to do this.

Comment: @RobertKujawa, Laravel 7 does this magically for us. No manual JS code needed on the FE, anyway, I found the answer to that for it.

Comment: Ok, I'm glad you found a solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution works but there is a built-in method for achieving your desired result in Laravel 7.

```
{{ $visitors->withQueryString()->links() }}
```

You can see your exact problem being solved in the attached PR: https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/31648

FYI, `links()` replaced `render()` in Laravel 5.3

Comment: Ok, I will use links going onward. Thanks for the tip;

Answer (score 1):

Add ->withQueryString(); to ->paginate(10);

Like this:
$visitors = Visitor::orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')->paginate(10)->withQueryString();

Comment: Perfect, If I have {{ $results->previousPageUrl() }} in blade file for custom buttons.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer to it. I updated my view

> {!! $visitors->render() !!}

to

> {!! $visitors->appends(Request::except('page'))->render() !!}

It doesn't replace my current URL params anymore.